# Horizontal LinearLayout with max width TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and two `TextView` children. My goal is to have the left `TextView` expand to fit its text content, but only up to a maximum width (to leave room for the right `TextView`). The key is I want to be able to express this maximum width in terms of a percentage similar to the way `layout_weight` is specified.

The problem with setting the `layout_weight` is that the `TextView` is then unconditionally expanded to fill the maximum width, even if the contents don't require the extra space.

Here's my current layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/subject"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0.8"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should bring the left textview into a framelayout. Then set textview wrap_content.

Comment: That actually didn't look too bad. The only thing was that the right `TextView` no longer hugs the right edge of the left `TextView`, but I may be able to live with that. Would still like to find a simpler way than nested layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a weight to one view only will only expand it to fill the space. If you want it to be relative you have to give the other view also weight in the layout.